# Interpolating Missing Values based on proxies in R

Tags: r

Assume that you have a proxy for a value that you want to measure.  the proxy has more data than your measure.  In this case, you may want to interpolate the measure based on your proxy.   for example,

```
set.seed(0)  ## so we can share the example
tv <- round(rnorm(10),3)
df <- data.frame( kept=round(tv,1), proxy=tv )
df$kept[3] <- NA; df$proxy[6] <- NA
t(df)
        [,1]   [,2] [,3]  [,4]  [,5] [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9] [,10]
 kept  1.300 -0.300   NA 1.300 0.400 -1.5 -0.900 -0.300  0.000 2.400
 proxy 1.263 -0.326 1.33 1.272 0.415   NA -0.929 -0.295 -0.006 2.405
```

the plan is to use the known proxy for the third observation to "patch in" the variable.

we first run a regression to understand how we can use our proxy to sub in.  the na.action=na.exclude makes sure we keep a length of 10 on our residuals and fitted variables.

```
 r <- lm( kept ~ proxy, na.action=na.exclude )
 coef(r)
 (Intercept)       proxy 
 -0.00009099  1.00054561
```

the solution is not obvious, because the predict function returns NA for a missing X variable.

```
predict(r)
      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10 
 1.3338 -1.2663      NA  0.3859 -0.9228      NA -1.7789  0.9991  0.7733  0.2960
```

the solution follows in the answer post.

Answer (score 1):

here is the puzzle solution

```
predict(r, newdata= df)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
 1.263598 -0.326269  1.330635  1.272603  0.415135        NA -0.929598 -0.295252 -0.006094  2.406221
```

use the newdata argument to the predict function.  this can conveniently pick off the correct variable names.